# How to evaluate the integral of $(2x+e^{-x})^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have tried for some time to evaluate

$$\int_0^2 (2x+e^{-x})^2 dx $$

but I have unfortunately beeen unsuccessful.

Could somebody be of help?

Comment: Consider adding any thoughts you have on the question, and showing why you are stuck.  This will help you to get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're familiar with the elementary integrals as well as integration by parts (if you're not, then just comment, I'll modify my answer accordingly). Expanding the square, you get $$\int_0^2 (4x^2+e^{-2x}+4xe^{-x})\,dx$$. The first and the second terms can be easily evaluated and the third term needs to be integrated by parts. Taking $4x$ as the differentiable function and $e^{-x}$ as the integrable function, just perform the integration and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the term and you will get an $x^2$ term,  $e^{-2x}$term and $xe^{-x}$term.

You know how to integrate the first two terms right?  The third term can be integrated by part. Hint:  $xe^{-x}dx=-xde^{-x}$ and then you can get the answer

Answer (score 1):

Expand first, and then integrate each of the three resulting terms $$(4x^2 + 4xe^{-x} + e^{-2x})$$ The middle term can be done with tabular integration, integration by parts, or by guessing.